# HTML Input Box with specific numbers only

Tags: javascript, html, input

I need an input text-box that can accept only string of 0's and 1's like 00101110101.

`<input type="number"></input>` restricts any letters to be entered, however, we can input 1,2,3,4 and so on. I need to restrict input string to consist only 0's and 1's.

Any way to do in HTML or with Javascript aid?

Comment: `pattern=[01]` If post-validation is acceptable. See an example here:  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: Just add a `change` event listener and strip any non binary characters. ie `var input = document.getElementById('binary-input');input.addEventListener('change', function(){input.value = input.value.replace(/[^0-1]/g, '')});` given `<input type="number" id="binary-input" placeholder="Only enter 0s and 1s"></input>`

Comment: Note that if the field is to be submitted to the server you'd need server-side validation too.

Comment: The '<input>' element does not have a closing tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression (`/[^01]/g`) and `replace` to remove anything except `0` and `1` from the input's value.

```js
document.getElementById("inp").oninput = function() {
  var v = this.value;           // get the value from the input
  v = v.replace(/[^01]/g, '');  // replace anything that isn't 0 or 1 by ''
  this.value = v;               // set the value of the input to the new value
}
```

```html
<input id="inp"/>
```

**If you want the user to still edit things in the middle,** then use this:

```js
document.getElementById("inp").oninput = function() {
  var pos = this.selectionStart; // save the position of the caret
  
  var v = this.value;
  v = v.replace(/[^01]/g, '');
  this.value = v;
  
  this.selectionStart = pos; // restore it
  this.selectionEnd = pos;   // so no text will be selected
}
```

```html
<input id="inp"/>
```

**Note** that I don't recommend using this last approach, as I'm not sure how many browsers handle `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`.

Comment: It'd be nicer for the user if you added a test to not update the value unless invalid characters are entered, because at the moment if one tries to edit an existing value by typing in the middle the cursor keeps moving to the end.

Comment: @nnnnnn but then they could paste an illegal value (that would be a bigger problem than this one).

Comment: Please don't. Code like this drives me insane as I never get to see what's wrong, far better to invalidate the input.

Comment: I said "unless invalid characters are entered", so no, pasted text wouldn't cause a problem, it would still be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 49'>
```

Hope it will help.
Regards.